# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent without permission BIND_INPUT_SERVICE

Tags: android, exception, service, permissions

> Hi I am working on soft keyboard.
>
> I am **getting exception of permission** when I am accessing my service
>   class from my simple activity class.
>
> **Stack Trace of exception** is shown below,

[image]

> In above image **InputServiceMethod class = Underlined by Green color**.
>
> **Activity class = Underlined by Blue color.**
>
> I am getting this exception when I am calling InputServiceMethod class
>   from activity class.
>
> For this I used the **below code which gives me exception**,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SoftKeyboard.class);
startService(intent);
finish();
```

> My **manifest file** as shown below,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.softkeyboard" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!--     <permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_SERVICE"  -->
<!--         android:exported="true"></permission> -->

    <application android:label="@string/ime_name">
        <service
            android:name="com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.configuration.Configuration"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_configuration" >
        </activity>
      </application>
```

I don't understand as even if I give **permission about BIND_INPUT_METHOD** it is throwing exception.

How to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are binding service to action `android.view.InputMethod` while it is protected by permission `android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD` which is used to ensure that only the system can bind to it by its protection level. So According to Android you can only define the keyboard handling service but can't call it explicitly, it will be called automatically by system whenever a input method is required. So there are two ways to solve it:
1. Let it be called by system, don't call it explicit, or
2. Sign your application with system's signature you are running on, which makes your application platform dependent. (Not advised if your building generic application).

Hope you understand the situation.

Comment: thanks for reply. But the problem is it is giving me exception when I try to use this app on older version now I am testing it on gingerbread 2.3.6. But it is fine working on any jelly bean device version 4+.

Comment: I don't think that is working fine as on android 4+ they just ignore the permissoin, but may be thrown in older version. By seeing the android's internal code (InputMethodManagerService) you can look that in 4+ they are ignoring without permission services.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj Nama it done the trick, as you said I used option 1, and in code I just used finish(); which worked just like device back button. As if I doesn't need to use this function, but to add just usablity of app I have to use back button explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The permission you are using i.e:
    permission about BIND_INPUT_METHOD
    is only for system apps and mostly will work only on rooted devices,
    it wont accept on unrooted devices.

Comment: Wrong answer bro. See my answer. It has nothing to do with rooted device.